# How to get ocurrences of a dictionary in a dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dictionary, join, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dictionary and a dataframe like these:

```
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, ...}

# Dataframe's column-names and type
dataframe[letters: Str, ...]
```

What I want to do is to get the rows of the dataframe of which 'letters' column-values coincide with the keys of the dictionary.

How can I do it?

Comment: how can `letters` be of type `int`? Your `key`s are all `str`ings.. Also post a few lines of the `dataframe`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I write it wrong